# C: Using pthreads and program is not exiting a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, pthreads

I am simulating a device that will receive bytes of data and write to a register when the clock has a falling edge. I've created a seperate pthread that will account for shifting the clock between high and low.

Now my issue is that in the main thread I have the console ask the user to type a hex value to write to the "device" and it then it calls a SendCommand(uint32_t addr, uint16_t data) function to do that. Since it is supposed to send one bit at a time per clock cycle, I have it in a for loop. Here is the send command function:

```
void SendCmd(uint32_t loadAddr, uint16_t data)
{
    dest = &loadAddr;
    int i;
    printf("%d\n\n",status);
    for(i=15; i>=0; --i) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&rising_edge, &data_lock);
        *dest = (*dest << 1)|(data & 0x8000) >> 15;
               //     ^^^^^^^^ get MSB
               //               ^^^^^ move the MSB down to the LSB, assuming the
               //                     peripheral wants the bit in the LSB.
        pthread_cond_wait(&falling_edge, &data_lock);
        data <<= 1;
        printf("%d\ti=%d\n",*dest,i);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_lock);
    status = ENABLED_IDLE;
}
```

When i=0, the loop should exit and return back to the main function where it will ask the user to enter another hex value. But it doesnt, and I can't seem to find why it would be stuck before exiting the loop.

EDIT: The freeze is actually occurring before the function ever executes:

```
int main()
{
    State status = DISABLED;
    Clock clk = LOW;
    int exit_flag = 0;
    char Command[20];
    pthread_t clk_t;
    pthread_cond_init(&en_sig, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&rising_edge, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&falling_edge, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&clk_lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&data_lock, NULL);
    pthread_create(&clk_t, NULL, simClk, NULL);
    while(!exit_flag)
    {
        if(status != ENABLED_ACTIVE)
        {
            fputs("(enable/disable/write [addr] [word_0] [word_1*]/quit): ", stdout);
            fflush(stdout);
            if ( fgets(Command, sizeof Command, stdin) != NULL )
            {
                char *newline = strchr(Command, '\n');
                if ( newline != NULL )
                {
                    *newline = '\0';
                }
            }

            if(strcasecmp(Command,"quit")==0)
            {
                printf("\nShutting Down!\n\n");
                pthread_cancel(&clk_t);
                pthread_mutex_destroy(&clk_lock);
                exit_flag = ~exit_flag;
                continue;
            }

            if(strcasecmp(Command,"enable")==0)
            {
                if(status != DISABLED)
                {
                    printf("\nSynthesizer is already enabled!\n\n");
                    continue;
                }
                status = ENABLED_IDLE;
                nanosleep(&ecsWait, NULL);
                printf("\nEnabled!\n\n");
                pthread_cond_signal(&en_sig);
                continue;
            }

            if(strcasecmp(Command,"disable")==0)
            {
                status = DISABLED;
               // pthread_mutex_lock(&clk_lock);
                printf("\nDisabled!\n\n");
                continue;
            }

            if(strcasecmp(Command,"w")==0)
            {
                if(status != ENABLED_IDLE)
                {
                    printf("\nSynthesizer is not enabled!\n\n");
                    continue;
                }
                printf("\nWriting!\n\n");
                status = ENABLED_ACTIVE;      //FREEZE OCCURS HERE!
                SendCmd(NREGISTER_ADDR,0xF13F);
                continue;
            }

            printf("Invalid command!\n");
        }
   }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `dest = &loadAddr` does not appear correct, it means you are writing to the address of the local variable `loadAddr`. If `loadAddr` is an actual address, maybe you meant to write something like `volatile uint8_t *dest = (uint8_t *) loadAddr`.

Comment: Are you seeing 16 lines of output per call?

Comment: The `i>=0` means the loop should exit when `i` hits `-1` not `0`, but since `i` is signed in your sample, the loop should still exit. What does the output of this look like? Does `i` continually decrement toward `-INT_MAX` or does it get corrupted somewhere?

Comment: Where is `pthread_mutex_lock(&data_lock)`?  It is usually a good idea to have matched pairs of locks and unlocks in the same function

Comment: @user4815162342 At the top of my class, I set a field to be volatile uint16_t *dest = NULL, because I want to simulate if I actually had an address to send it to.

Comment: @iwolf No the program just stops, and the console just freezes, although the cursor still blinks, which means its not entirely stuck. At Dohashi, I thought that when you call a conditional wait, that it automatically locks the mutex for you.

Comment: The docs for `pthread_cond_wait()` say, in part, "shall be called with [the mutex] locked by the calling thread or undefined behavior results".  It looks like the UB you are experiencing turns out to include that  `pthread_cond_wait()` never returns.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've added mutex_locks before each call to the pthread_cond_wait, but now the program doesnt even iterate through one loop. What I have done is forloop{lock,cond_wait,unlock,lock,cond_wait,unlock}, with some data processing in between.

Comment: You're supposed to hold the mutex when you call `pthread_cond_wait()`, but you don't need to acquire it again if you already hold it.  In fact, trying to do so may cause your program to deadlock, depending on the properties of the mutex.  It looks like you should lock the mutex once, before the beginning of the loop, and not elsewhere in the function.  That one mutex acquisition is paired with the one mutex release, as @dohashi observed should be the case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried that, however now the function doesnt even enter the loop, or if it does, it still freezes (earlier than before). I lock the mutex before the start of the loop, and I unlock it after the loop.

Comment: Im starting to find out that the freeze is occuring before it even gets into the function.

Comment: You are also meant to hold the mutex when you call `pthread_cond_signal`. It drops it internally, then retakes it.

Comment: @abligh im not entirely sure what you mean by that

Comment: @GBoggs you must call `pthread_cond_signal` between `pthread_mutex_lock` and `phread_mutex_unlock`. `pthread_cond_signal` itself internally unlocks and relocks the mutex. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html for example, and note the phrase _'Call pthread_cond_signal() under the protection of the same mutex used with the condition variable being signaled. Otherwise, the condition variable could be signaled between the test of the associated condition and blocking in `pthread_cond_wait()`, which can cause an infinite wait.'_ - that may be what you are seeing

Answer (score 2):

The issue: the main thread needs to call `pthread_cond_wait` *before* the other thread calls `pthread_cond_signal`.  If the other thread signals the condition before the main thread is waiting for the condition, then `pthread_cond_wait` will never return.

So you need to make sure that things happen in the proper order, and that's where the mutex comes in.  You should lock the mutex *before* creating the other thread, and only unlock the mutex when you are finished using the condition variable. The other thread needs to lock the mutex, signal the condition, and unlock the mutex.

Pseudo code for the main thread

```
init mutex
lock the mutex
init condition variable
create the other thread
while ( !done )
{
   wait for condition
   do something useful after the condition is signaled 
}
unlock the mutex
```

Pseudo code for the other thread when it wants to signal the condition

```
lock the mutex
signal the condition 
unlock the mutex
```

Obvious question: "But if the main thread always has the mutex locked, how will the other thread ever get the mutex?".  Answer: "`pthread_cond_wait` internally unlocks the mutex, that's why you pass the mutex to `pthread_cond_wait`."